# Javascript/Form call timing

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I have a form that I use for login purposes here:

```
<form id = "membershipInfo" method = "post" action = "Login.aspx">
```

with an submit button that I want to do a post method and a javascript onclick method like this:

```
<input type ="submit" id = "submitInfo" class = "MemberInfo" value = "Take Me There!" onclick = "authorize(accept, reject)"/>
```

The method in the onclick is an facebook authorize method that will pull information from the user (access token). I need this token to have the user proceed in my program. The issue is that when this button is clicked the post method will happen before the onclick is finished, which means that the access token will never be passed with the form.

To get the access token to the page load method I use a hidden input in the form:

```
<input type = "hidden" id = "hiddenAccessToken"  name = "accessToken" value = "<%=accessToken %>" />
```

and in the Facebook method I get the access token like this:

```
function authorize(successCallback, failureCallback) {
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.session) {
        // logged in and connected user, carry on
        session = response.session;
        //Set access token
        accessToken = response.session.access_token;
        //Call success callback
        successCallback();
    } else {
        // no user session available, Lets ask for perms
        FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'permissions.request',
            perms:  permissionString
        },
        function (response) {
            if (response && response.session != null) {
                //Get session
                session = response.session;
                //Set access token
                accessToken = response.session.access_token;
                //Call success callback
                successCallback();
            } else {
                //Call failure callback
                failureCallback();
            }
        });
    }
});
//Method hit on successCallback
function accept() {
   //Add access token to hidden input
   $('#hiddenAccessToken').val(accessToken);
}
```

I don't want to use a time out (and I don't think that will work anyways), but I need to slow the page load down until these js methods are complete. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do the form submit with js, like this:

```
<input type ="button" id = "submitInfo" class = "MemberInfo" value = "Take Me There!" onclick = "authorize(accept, reject)"/>
```

And then:

```
function accept() {
   //Add access token to hidden input
   $('#hiddenAccessToken').val(accessToken);
   $('#membershipInfo').submit();
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. Good call